# Shift Operators and the Weyl Algebra

Tags: co.combinatorics, differential-operators, infinite-sequences, weyl-algebra

I have a question about the action of a shift operator $E$ on polynomials $Ep(x) = p(x+1)$ in the context of linear differential operators in one variable with polynomial coefficients, i.e. differential operators of the form $Y_n = \sum_{i=0}^n p_{n,i}(x) \partial_x^i$, where $p_{n,i}(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

Given a sequence $a = (a_1 =1, a_2, \dotsc)$ of complex numbers whose first entry is $1$, does there exist a sequence $\{Y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of linear differential operators with polynomial coefficients with $Y_0 = \mathrm{id}$ such that $EY_n = \sum_{k=1}^n B_{n,k}(a_1, \dotsc, a_{n-k+1}) Y_k$, where the shift operator acts as $EY_n =\sum_{i=0}^n p_{n,i}(x+1) \partial_x^i$ and $B_{n,k}$ are the partial exponential Bell polynomials.

I have read already about the work of Roman and Rota on umbral calculus, and also the more recent work of Shapiro, Sprugnoli, Wang, etc on Riordan arrays, which I think are relevant. However I still can't seem to find a way to answer this, let alone compute the array of polynomials.

**Update:**

By assuming $Y_1= \partial_x $ and $Y_n = (a_{n,n-1}x^{n-1} + \dotsb a_{n, 1}x) \partial_x$ for $n >1$ (where $a_{n,i} \in \mathbb{C}$) then the condition above reduces to
$ \sum_{k=1}^n B_{n,k} a_{k,i} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {{k}\choose{i}} a_{n,k} $ for $0 \leq i \leq n-2$ and $a_{n,i}=0$ if $i \geq n$ and $a_{n,0}=0$ if $n>1$.

At each order $n$, by plugging in values for $i$, this relation gives a linear system of $n-1$ equations with $n-1$ new unknowns (in terms of the variables $a_{r,i}$, $r <n$). Hence such a sequence of differential operators does exist, however I am still not sure how to find a closed form for the $a_{n,i}$ if it exists.